# iOS is it possible to insert records automatically at specific date and time?

Tags: ios, core-data

I don't know where to start.
I use core data in iOS and I would like to insert records automatically. 
The user can choose the days and time. Once he chosen, I would like to automatically insert the record without his intervention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
NSDate *selectedDate = ...;            
NSTimeInterval timeTillNextUpdate = [selectedDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
[self performSelector:@selector(insertRecord) withObject:nil afterDelay:timeTillNextUpdate];
```

Comment: Would be perfect, but it does not work in background and when the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

what is this for? User has chosen the time, you store it. While your app is opened you can do anything with core data and this time without any intervention

Comment: Sorry, I have not explained well. I know that way. I have this problem when the app closed. Thanks

Comment: @Ziggy you can use notifications OR just do the job when app becomes active. Maybe you can describe your task more detailed. In ordinary cases it's enough to check queued job when app enters foreground and do the stuff with core data